# required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

**I am getting following error whenever started application spring boot.**

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field session in com.base.model.AbstractDao required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in your configuration.

I have added implementation of my application:

**POM.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>


    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate dependency -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.property

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"configure"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.base","com.base.model"});
        sessionFactory.setMappingResources(new String[]{"Employee.hbm.xml"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hiberante.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
            dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.userName"));
            dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean  
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf){  
        return hemf.getSessionFactory();  
    }  

}
```

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String country;

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country){
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCountry(){
        return this.getCountry();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", country="
                + country + "]";
    }
}
```

**Employee.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.base.model.Employee" table="Person">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>

        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="name" not-null="true"></column>
        </property>
        <property name="country" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="country"></column>
        </property>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**EmployeeDaoImpl**

```
@Component
public class EmployeeDataDaoImpl  {


    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public List<Employee> findAllEmployee(){
////    Criteria cri = getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);
//  List<Employee> dbList = cri.list();
//  for (Employee employee : dbList) {
//      System.out.println(employee.getCountry());
//  }
    return null;
}

}
```

I have looked up the same error code on stackoverflow but none of the solutions worked and thus posting it here again with my code.
Hoping someone else can point out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For starters there are a couple of things of with your configuration

1. Mixing jars from different Spring and Hibernate versions
2. Too may already managed dependencies
3. Trying to be smarter then Spring Boot.

For 1. and 2. just remove the `<version>` tag for `spring-orm` and the `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entitymanager` manager dependencies. Spring Boot is already managing those. You can actually remove all the `org.springframework` dependencies those are already pulled in by the starters (and actually the hibernate ones also).

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Next in your configuration you have at least 2 `SessionFactory`'s configured. I would suggest to use annotations to define your entities instead of `hbm.xml` files.

```
@Entity
@Table("person")
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    private String country;

}
```

When using JPA annotations Hibernate will automatically detect your entities (especially combined with Spring Boot) which makes it very powerful. Ofcourse you can now remove your `Employee.hbm.xml`.

Next your `EmployeeDataDaoImpl` I strongly suggest to use plain JPA over plain Hibernate. Generally that provides enough for you to work with.

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDataDaoImpl  {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManger;


    public List<Employee> findAllEmployee(){
        return em.createQuery("select e from Employee e", Employee.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

With this setup you can basically completely remove your `HibernateConfiguration`. Yes you can as Spring Boot detects Hibernate and automatically creates a `JpaTransactionManager`, enables transactions and preconfigured a `EntityManagerFactory`.

If you really want to use plain hibernate with a `SessionFactory` just use a `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` to expose the underlying `SessionFactory` of the `EntityManagerFactory`.

```
@Bean
public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return factory;
}
```

However as mentioned I would strongly suggest to use plain JPA as that is a lot easier to setup and with the current state of JPA it offers almost as much of the functionality as plain Hibernate does.

*Pro Tip*
You have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` which means you are having a dependency on Spring Data JPA. Which would make things even easier if you would use JPA. You can remove your `EmployeeDataDaoImpl` and just create an interface and use that.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

That is it, all the CRUD methods (`findOne`, `findAll`, `save` etc.) are provided for you without you having to create an implementation.

Comment: I am still getting "... Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!" when using the @Bean HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean. I had to add "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext" to application.properties

Comment: How can I custom with it

Answer (score 4):

Your SessionFactory configuration is wrong. From your pom.xml I see you are using hibernate version 5, so your configuration should be:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

And also you have different versions of hibernate jars in your pom.xml, try to use same versions.

Comment: Thanks for your response but problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed the wrong Class name inside of Main-Class:

Path: resouces -> META-INF -> MANIFEST.NF