# Correct and complete configuration for Spring Boot 1.5.x for Hibernate 5

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-5.x

About `Spring Boot` for the `1.5.10.RELEASE` version.
It works internally around with `Hibernate` for version `5.0.12.Final`

With the purpose to avoid the following error message:

```
required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found
```

The `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` class should be applied. It according from:

- [required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533691/required-a-bean-of-type-org-hibernate-sessionfactory-that-could-not-be-found)

The situation here is the `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` class is `@Deprecated`.

The solution how is suggested according the [HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.html), is work around with `EntityManagerFactory#unwrap`

Thus from:

- [Spring Boot - Handle to Hibernate SessionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063995/spring-boot-handle-to-hibernate-sessionfactory/25064080)

**manually** must be declared the following:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```

**Warning** is mandatory include in the `application.properties` file the following (it is not mentioned in the post shared above):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class = 
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Otherwise appears:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException:
No CurrentSessionContext configured!; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:
No CurrentSessionContext configured!
```

Until here my `@Test` classes working through `Hibernate` fails, these same `@Test` classes pass in other project working through `Spring Framework`, thus all the infrastructure for `Hibernate` is declared manully.

Therefore through the following code:

```
@Test
public void contextLoads() {

    String[] beanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        logger.info("beanName: {}", beanName);
    }

    logger.info("PlatformTransactionManager");
    if(transactionManager != null) {
        logger.info("Class: {}", transactionManager.getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

all the `beans` created by `Spring Boot` are printed and I have confirmed the following:

```
 - PlatformTransactionManager 
 - Class: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
```

I expected the `HibernateTransactionManager` instead of `JpaTransactionManager`.

My unique way to get the `@Test` methods passing is declaring again **manually** other `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Therefore:

- What is the correct and complete configuration for `Spring Boot 1.5.x` for `Hibernate 5`?

**Observation**: even better if all is completely configured through the `application.properties` file (purpose avoid declare *manually* any `@Bean`)

How a summary, the unique way to integrate `Spring Boot` for *plain* `Hibernate` (Consider the scenario to migrate a *complete* project working through `Spring Framework` to `Spring Boot` working both with `Hibernate`)
is through the following:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.provider_class = org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class = org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size = 30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.max_fetch_depth = 30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates = true;
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments = true
```

Plus these two mandatories `@Beans`

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

**Without** these two `@Beans` I have all the **two** errors already reported.

Therefore the **goal** is configure `Hibernate` **just** through `application.properties`

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggest (Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE)

File **application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vy
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

File **BeanConfig.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }
        return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

}
```

File **UserDao.java**

```
package com.example.dao;

import com.example.model.UserDetails;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserDao {

    List<UserDetails> getUserDetails();

}
```

File **UserDaoImpl.java** where use SessionFactory

```
package com.example.dao.impl;

import com.example.dao.UserDao;
import com.example.model.UserDetails;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<UserDetails> getUserDetails() {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.openSession().createCriteria(UserDetails.class);
        return criteria.list();
    }

}
```

> the goal is configure Hibernate just through application.properties

--> It is ok with JPA implementation using Hibernate Session. Spring Data JPA is tight integrated with Spring Boot (at least I checked with SpringBoot 2.0.0.RC1). Configuration via `application.properties`, under the hood, Spring Boot is auto-configuration.

It is not ok with full features of Hibernate ORM.

Comment: It is a working example: https://github.com/donhuvy/sample_boot3  in pom.xml, change version of Spring Boot to `1.5.10.RELEASE`

Comment: Let me check in detail your answer this weekend... thanks

Comment: If you want use latest technology stack (Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC2, Hibernate 5.2.13.Final, JDK 9.0.4) do like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49014346/3728901