# Springboot : Hibernate Configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have added application.properties file , given below :

> Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties) spring.datasource.url =
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
>   spring.datasource.username = root spring.datasource.password = root
>
> Hibernate Properties
>    The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
>
> Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update) spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
>
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext

for dao layer, class :

```
package com.repository;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class DaoClass
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

now on running the springboot application, i am facing below error :

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field sessionFactory in com.repository.DaoClass required a bean of
>   type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' in
>   your configuration.

POM.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>springboot</groupId>
 <artifactId>firstprogram</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
 <name>firstprogram Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>   
  </dependency>

 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <finalName>firstprogram</finalName>
 </build>
</project>
```

i have also add 
[image]

```
package com.repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DaoClass
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManger;

    public EntityManager getEntityManger()
    {
        return entityManger;
    }

    public void setEntityManger(EntityManager entityManger)
    {
        this.entityManger = entityManger;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' that could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533691/required-a-bean-of-type-org-hibernate-sessionfactory-that-could-not-be-found)

Comment: on adding the above solution , facing nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot doesn't auto configure `SessionFactory`, instead it configures the `EntityManagerFactory` which you can use directly or obtain a `SessionFactory` from it in the following way:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
```

Comment: i thought we are using `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext` to configure sessionfactory